# Ranging over a slice

Tags: go

my problem is that Im only allowed to use the command PrintRune, i must range over a string and print one by one the characters of any string

```
package piscine

import "github.com/01-edu/z01"

func PrintStr(s string) {
    slice := []string{
        s,
    }
    for x, word := range slice {
        z01.PrintRune(rune(word[x]))
    }
}
```

here's my code, this only prints the first character of the string, how can i make the slice continue until the end of the given string please ?

Comment: `for _, r := range s { z01.PrintRune(r) }`

Comment: If you add 2 or 3 strings of size 1 (like “a”,”b”,”c”) you will see a big surprise. Probably because you do not pay attention that you need to perform two loops

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code snippets:

```
package piscine

import "github.com/01-edu/z01"

func PrintStr(s string) {
    slice := []string{
        s,
    }
    for _, word := range slice {
        for _, r := range word {
            z01.PrintRune(rune(r))
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Drop `slice`, what's the use of creating a slice with a single element and looping over it? All you need is `for _, r := range s { z01.PrintRune(r) }`.

Comment: @icza You are absolutely right: For single string element, we don't need to create `Slice`.

But as per OP's question and code snippet that OP posted above and I quote "how can i make the slice continue ...":  I assumed OP want to iterate over the `Slice` so I didn't changed the OP's original code snippet.